# ListView do Android não exibe o primeiro item

Tags: java, android, listview

Primeiramente obrigado por tentarem ajudar, vamos lá!

Eu possuo um projeto feito no Android Studio onde contém um ListView personalizado que eu usava junto com meu banco de dados INTERNO.
Após o projeto ter evoluído, mudei meu banco de dados para EXTERNO, e estou usando o MYSQL como banco de dados.

O problema é o seguinte: 
Após mudar para banco de dados EXTERNO o meu `ListView` personalizado não exibe o primeiro resultado da lista.
Ou seja, tenho um adapter chamado "adpJogos" que está populando a lista do `ListView` com variáveis retiradas de um objetos, porém, quando ele só contem apenas um objeto para popular o `ListView`, o `ListView` vem vazio como se não tivesse nenhum item, porém, após adicionar outro objeto no `Adapter`, o `ListView` exibe os 2 objetos de uma vez.

Segue meu código para criar o adapter e setar ele no `ListView`:

```
public class ActApp extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView lstComentarios;

    private ArrayAdapter < Comentario > adpJogos;

    @
    Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.act_cad2_app_comentarios);
        lstComentarios = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstComentarios);

        adpJogos = repositorioJogos.buscaJogos(this, id);

        lstComentarios.setAdapter(adpJogos);
    }
}
```

Segue meu código do "repositórioJogos" que é responsável por popular a ListView com itens retirados de um Objeto:

```
public class RepositorioJogos {

    private SQLiteDatabase conn;

    public RepositorioJogos(SQLiteDatabase conn) {
        this.conn = conn;
    }

    public ListView buscaJogos(Context context, int id) {

        ListView adpJogos = new ListView(context, R.layout.listview);

        UsuarioDAO dao = new UsuarioDAO();
        ArrayList < Comentario > usr = dao.preencherListView(id);

        if (usr != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < usr.size(); i++) {

                Comentario comentario = new Comentario();
                comentario.setComentarioJogo(usr.get(i).getComentarioJogo());
                comentario.setUsuario(usr.get(i).getUsuario());

                adpJogos.add(comentario);
            }

            return adpJogos;
        }

        return adpJogos;
    }
}
```

Segue o código dos itens da ListView personalizada:

```
public class ListView extends ArrayAdapter < Comentario > {

    private int resource = 0;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListView(Context context, int resource) {

        super(context, resource);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @Override 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = null;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            view = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);

            viewHolder.txtusuario = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtusuario);
            viewHolder.txtcomentario = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtcomentario);

            view.setTag(viewHolder);

            convertView = view;

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            view = convertView;
        }

        Comentario comentario = getItem(position);

        viewHolder.txtcomentario.setText(comentario.getComentarioJogo());
        viewHolder.txtusuario.setText(comentario.getUsuario());

        return view;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtusuario;
        TextView txtcomentario;
    }
}
```

Se precisarem de algo mais, como por exemplo o código que está no `dao.preencherListView` é só pedir, mais se trata apenas de um simples `SELECT coluna FROM tabela`. Qualquer dúvida também só perguntar.

Obrigado

Editado:
Segue o código do dao.preencherListView:

> public ArrayList preencherListView(int id){
>          ArrayList lista = new ArrayList();
>
> ```
>   SoapObject buscarUsuarios = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, PREENCHERLISTVIEW);
>   buscarUsuarios.addProperty("id", id);
>
>  SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
>
>   envelope.setOutputSoapObject(buscarUsuarios);
>
>   envelope.implicitTypes = true;
>
>   HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
>
>   try{
>       http.call("urn" + PREENCHERLISTVIEW, envelope);
>
>      Vector<SoapObject> resposta = (Vector<SoapObject>) envelope.getResponse();
>
>      for (SoapObject soapobject : resposta) {
>
>            Comentario usr = new Comentario();
>
>           usr.setId( Integer.parseInt(soapobject.getProperty("id").toString()));
>
>  usr.setComentarioJogo(soapobject.getProperty("comentarioJogo").toString());
>
>           usr.setUsuario(soapobject.getProperty("usuario").toString());
>
>            lista.add(usr);
>        }
>    } catch (Exception e) {
>        e.printStackTrace();
>        return null;
> ```

EDITADO:
Esqueci do código para acessar o banco de dados, que o dao acessa:

> public ArrayList preencherListView(int id){
>         ArrayList lista = new ArrayList();
>
> ```
>   try{
>           Connection conn = ConectaMySql.obtemConexao();
>           String queryInserir = "SELECT * FROM comentario WHERE JOGOID = ?";
>
>           PreparedStatement ppStm = conn.prepareStatement(queryInserir);
>           ppStm.setInt(1, id);
>
>           ResultSet rSet = ppStm.executeQuery();
>
>           while(rSet.next()){
>               Comentario usr = new Comentario();
>
>               usr.setId(rSet.getInt(1));
>               usr.setComentarioJogo(rSet.getString(3));
>               usr.setUsuario(rSet.getString(5));
>
>               lista.add(usr);
>           }
>
>               conn.close();
>           } catch (Exception e){
>               e.printStackTrace();
>           }   
>
>           return lista;
>   }
> ```

Comment: O que tem no arquivo no seu `adapter` `adpJogos`?

Comment: Nada, ele não é um arquivo. É somente um ArrayAdapter que é usado somente no comando: "adpJogos = repositorioJogos.buscaJogos(this, id);" ..e é enviado para o "repositórioJogos" para ser populado e depois esse adpJogos e adicionado no ListView. Porém, no "repositórioJogos" é criado outro adpJogos com formado ListView, e os códigos para ele está na terceira citação, na classe de nome ListView.

Comment: E esse dao.preencherListView(id)? Como está montado? Deixa eu ver se consigo te ajudar.

Comment: Pronto amigo. ..editei a pergunta e coloquei o código "dao.preencherListView" e o código do eclipse para acessar o banco da dados. Obrigado por tentar ajudar.

Comment: Bom, você realiza a `query` e retorna 1 resultado, porém não exibe na `listview`? Certo?!

Comment: Essa query busca no banco de dados os valores correspondentes ao "id" que foi pedido e armazena em forma de um objeto "comentário". Porém,pode haver mais de um resultado com o mesmo "id",por isso ele tem esse loop para pegar todos os resultados que possuem o mesmo "id" e colocar em um array.O problema é:quando há somente um objeto armazenado no array, a listview fica vazia,mais quando adiciona mais algum objeto com o mesmo "id" (ou seja, tem mais de um objeto dentro do array), ele mostra normal a listview. Ou seja, ou a listview mostra 0 itens ou mostra 2+. Ela nao mostra quando tem 1 item só.

Comment: Resumindo é assim: Minha tabela comentário possui 3 itens:"id","comentario" e "usuario". Porém, pode haver mais de um "id" igual. Por isso, eu crio esse array chamado "lista" e coloco tdos os objetos que forem encontrados dentro dela.Então exemplo:Se eu tenho na tabela 1 linha só com o mesmo id (exemplo: 5),ele deveria mostrar na ListView um item. Se eu tenho 2 linhas com o id 5 (como no exemplo) deveria mostrar 2 itens e assim por diante (por isso tem o loop). Porém,a ListView só mostra 0 itens ou 2+ itens, ela não mostra quando tem apenas 1 item(se a tabela possui apenas 1 linha com o id 5).

Comment: Tenta chamar o refresh pro adapter do listview após carregar os dados: **adpJogos.notifyDataSetChanged();**

Comment: Tentei cara, mais não mudou nada. Parece que o ListView não exibe mesmo o item 1, já tentei de tudo que consigo imaginar e nada. Deve ser algo na programação mesmo que deixei passar ou sei lá.